# How to fix getting audit for a time period

Tags: powershell, date, sharepoint

First it was getting a data for a particular date,ex:01/12/2018 to now.it gets data between 01/12/2018 to 04/12/2018 and stops there

when I changed to get it from different time period like from 05/12/2019.It  still gets only 04/12/2019 and doesn't progress.

```
$site=get-spsite $siteurl;
$siteaudit=$site.Audit;
$filterQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAuditQuery($site);
$startDate='05/12/2018';
$filterQuery.SetRangeStart($startDate);
$siteAuditEntries = $siteAudit.GetEntries($filterQuery);
```

Audit script to get data from actual time period given.

Comment: I assume `2019` is a typo. Would you be able to see if there is any data to show past `04/12/2018`?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.spauditquery.setrangestart?view=sharepoint-server), you should use a `DateTime` object for the `SetRangeStart` function, not a string.

You can get the wanted start date as `DateTime` object in a number of ways like for instance any of these:

- `$startDate = [datetime]::new(2018, 5,12)`
- `$startDate = [datetime]'05/12/2018'`
- `$startDate = [datetime]::ParseExact('05/12/2018', 'MM/dd/yyyy', $null)`
- `$startDate = Get-Date -Year 2018 -Month 5 -Day 12 -Hour 0 -Minute 0 -Second 0`

Does that help?

Comment: Hi,Thanks I have converted the string to date-time.It doesn't seems to be fixed

Comment: @saimonesh I couldn't find real working examples, but perhaps you have to set  `$filterQuery.SetRangeEnd((Get-Date))` aswell?

Answer (score 0):

```
#For Example Use Previous Hour
$startDate = (Get-Date).AddHours(-1)
```

or you can reference this site
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/adding-and-subtracting-dates-with-powershell/